# How to combine multiple plugin files in one folder in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, file, plugins, merge, structure

I have several plugins that communicate with Apipee.Each plugin contains only from one php file. My task is to put all these plugins in one folder for better usability.

I created a folder and moved the php files in that folder. I removed the headers from the plugins and created loader.php file in the same folder. The content of loader.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Combined Plugin
Description: Contains plugin a, plugin b and plugin c
*/
 include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-a.php';
 include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-b.php';
 include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-c.php';
 ?>
```

For some reason the plugins does not work at all. The plguin appears and can be activated. But none of the plugins does anything.

Comment: what doesn't work ? the combined plugin doesn't appear in the plugin list ? one of the plugin returns a wrong answer ? please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I added the question. The plugins should get or post requests from Apigee. They were working perfectly till I combined all files in one folder. Is the content of loader.php correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format of getting the plugin path.

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'plugin-a.php';
```

Using the keyword `require` will cause a fatal error when the specified file location is invalid so you know if the path is correctly being referenced then.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got a fatal error and found that that i forgot the .php extension at the end of one of the files. Now is good!